# Computing Highlight Tint Color in iOS 7 e.g. in UISegmentedView

Tags: ios, ios7, uisegmentedcontrol, uicolor, tintcolor

I would like to create an algorithm for computing highlight tint color from a given tint color for my custom UI controls.

By highlight tint color I mean the color which is shown in standard iOS UI controls like UISegmentedView when highligting items. See here:

[image]

Is there an official information regarding the way how this color is computed? Are there any open source libraries (e.g. for custom components) which would compute the color? Or is there an UIColor category which would do exactly what I want to achieve?

Comment: Not official but a quick screenshot & photoshop tells me it is same  color with 15% opacity.

Comment: Good first try! I've tested it in my control and it looks pretty accurate. I would still like to wait if there is something official. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As *Desdenova* mentioned in a comment, it really seems like the highlight tint color is the same color as the tint color with 15% opacity. I've created a simple category which creates this color from the tint color.

*UIColor+HighlightTintColor.h*

```
@interface UIColor (HighlightTintColor)

- (instancetype)highlightTintColor;
+ (instancetype)highlightTintColorForTintColor:(UIColor *)tintColor;

@end
```

*UIColor+HighlightTintColor.m*

```
#import "UIColor+HighlightTintColor.h"

@implementation UIColor (HighlightTintColor)

- (instancetype)highlightTintColor
{
    return [[self class] highlightTintColorForTintColor:self];
}

+ (instancetype)highlightTintColorForTintColor:(UIColor *)tintColor
{
    return [tintColor colorWithAlphaComponent:0.15];
}

@end
```

If there are better suggestions, please post your answers and if they are better than this one, I will accept them.